# Javascript to group and sum 2 arrays by matching value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I'm using Javascript and I have two arrays which I need to combine into one and pass the resulting array to `Highcharts`, but the arrays need to be grouped and summated for each matching value in the `symbolArray`.

```
Input Arrays
var symbolArray = ["GSK", "VOD", "VOD", "GSK", "VOD"];
var valueArray = [100, 220, 120, 230, 155];

// Group symbolArray by each unique value (VOD, GSK) and
// summate the values in valueArray matching each unique value.

Output Arrays
var GroupBysymbolArray = ["GSK", "VOD"];
var GroupByvalueArray = [330, 495];

HighchartsArray = [GSK, VOD, 330, 495]
```

I can setup an jsfiddle if required.

Comment: _“I can setup an jsfiddle if required.”_ - would that contain the actual attempt you made then, prior to asking here? If not, then I don’t see the point.

Comment: Understood CBroe, I tried looking for an example of my problem on here before posting the call, but was unable to find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd run over both arrays, and accumulate them to an object where the key is the symbol and the value is summed. Then, you can extract the keys and the values:

```js
var symbolArray = ["GSK", "VOD", "VOD", "GSK", "VOD"];
var valueArray = [100, 220, 120, 230, 155];

const sum = {}
for (let i = 0; i < symbolArray.length; ++i) {
    const symbol = symbolArray[i];
    if (!sum[symbol]) {
        sum[symbol] = valueArray[i];
    } else {
        sum[symbol] += valueArray[i];
    }
}

const groupBySymbolArray = Object.keys(sum);
const groupByValueArray = Object.values(sum);
```

**Note:**
This snippet assumes the input is correct and both arrays contain the right data types and are the same length.
In a "real" scenario, you may want to add some validations.

Comment: Thank you Mureinik that does exactly what is required, good point about the validation. Cheers Colin

Comment: Mureinik, I have integrated the above into my code and it is grouping the Highcharts as required which is great. thanks Colin

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in following steps:

- Create an empty object `obj`.
- use `forEach()` over the symbols array. And group all corresponding values to their keys. Such that `obj` have keys as symbols and values as array of corresponding values
- Then loop over object and calculate sum for each symbol.
- Then create a final output array using `Object.keys` `Object.values`

```js
const obj = {};
var symbolArray = ["GSK", "VOD", "VOD", "GSK", "VOD"];
var valueArray = [100, 220, 120, 230, 155];
symbolArray.forEach((sym, i) => {
  obj[sym] = (obj[sym] || []).concat(valueArray[i]);
})

for(let k in obj){
  obj[k] = obj[k].reduce((ac, a) => a + ac, 0);
}
const res = [...Object.keys(obj), ...Object.values(obj)];
console.log(res)
```

A more cleaner way is just use a single `reduce()`

```js
var symbolArray = ["GSK", "VOD", "VOD", "GSK", "VOD"];
var valueArray = [100, 220, 120, 230, 155];

const obj = symbolArray.reduce((ac, a, i) => ({...ac, [a]: (ac[a] || 0) + valueArray[i]}), {});
const res = [...Object.keys(obj), ...Object.values(obj)];
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks Maheer Ali, I now have a couple of options, I will test both sets of code and integrate one into my system. Cheers Colin

Comment: @colin You are welcome. I added another solution using a single `reduce()` only. Make sure to check it out

Comment: Hi Maheer Ali, That last solution is a good option, works on my system.. many thanks Colin